# How to maintain employee hierarchy in a single table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have employees table where I am storing the employee details.

Also I have roles table which contains following roles

1. CEO
2. VP
3. Director
4. Manager
5. Developer

CEO doesn’t report to anybody and apart from CEO every other employee reports to someone else. And apart from “Developer” role every other role can have multiple reporter. So how can I achieve this in rails.

**EDIT**
Table structure is as follows

```
create_table "employees", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email"
    t.string "phone"
    t.integer "role_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["role_id"], name: "index_employees_on_role_id"
end

create_table "roles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "desc"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

Comment: What is your current schema?

Comment: @escanxr I have added the table schema

Comment: Hum it depends of your future needs but a self join association could be a good path to follow. I personnaly like to use Ancestry gem (https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) but it could be a little too "big" for a basic usage.

Answer (score 0):

you can do a self association with the employee table for example:

```
has_many :employees, class_name: 'Employee'
belongs_to :manager, class_name: 'Employee', optional: true
```